# ubuntu 18.04performing slow after I swapped sata2 HDD with sata2 ssd

Tags: 18.04, ssd

Recently I replaced my internal HDD with SSD, since then my code is executing slow.

Previously it took roughly 5 sec to execute now it takes around ten minutes.

When i did fsck from grub it showed following result:

[image: fsck]

```
$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for shivaksingh: 
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="648A5D678A5D36B0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e2cbf64a-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="B20C5F560C5F1527" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e2cbf64a-02"
/dev/sda5: UUID="1c96a5ea-42e4-4188-89fc-26aa4cb9b5fe" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e2cbf64a-05"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=1c96a5ea-42e4-4188-89fc-26aa4cb9b5fe /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw
```

---

```
$ free -h
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache  available
Mem:           7.7G        1.2G        5.6G        239M        963M        6.0G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

---

```
$ swapon
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G   0B   -2
```

---

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 34.8 MiB, 36503552 bytes, 71296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 3.7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 14.5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 128.5 MiB, 134746112 bytes, 263176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 7.5 MiB, 7811072 bytes, 15256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe2cbf64a

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 262252825 262045978   125G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       262254590 488396799 226142210 107.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       262254592 488396799 226142208 107.9G 83 Linux




Disk /dev/loop8: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 34.6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 91 MiB, 95416320 bytes, 186360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: have you checked the disk? Use `fsck`

Comment: do you want me to unmount and then remount? I mean how will it help?

Comment: Yes the procedure is to 1. Unmount, 2. fsch, 3. mount

Comment: I did it nothing changed, infact i did it from grub and it aborted. Coudn't unmount.

Comment: Which code is executing slower? How have you benchmarked your system?

Comment: Timing cached reads:   14646 MB in  2.00 seconds = 7340.05 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1584 MB in  3.00 seconds = 527.95 MB/sec

I'm running python with mpl_toolkit, astropy, xlswriter.

Comment: In 18.xx, you have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to run fsck on your SSD. How did you copy your HDD to SSD? Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `free -h` and `swapon` and `fdisk -l`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I didn't copy any thing from HDD to SSD, I used git to clone my code.

Comment: But you said "I replaced my internal HDD with SSD". Did you do my answer successfully?

Comment: @heynnema  yes I replaced my HDD with SSD i brought the code back using cloning. 
Yes I did you answer but nothing has changed

Comment: Does anything else run slow, or just your code? Briefly, what does your code do? All the question edits look fine. I don't see any problem there.

Comment: @heynnema backup fails every time it takes 3-4 hours and then fails though i only got ubuntu 18.04 files and a 50 mb folder. The speed of my external harddisk is pretty decent.

Comment: @ShivakSIngh  Sounds like you're having more problems than just code slowness. Backups also fail. I'd start over. First check that your SSD firmware is up to date. Then re-init the SSD, but this time, do it as GPT, not MBR, partitioning tables. Then reinstall Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema what does re-init the ssd mean?

Comment: @ShivakSIngh re-init means to wipe the drive and start over. I'm recommending that you use the GPT style partition tables, instead of what you currently use, which is MBR. Then reinstall Windows and Ubuntu from scratch. Although it can be a lot of work, I think the end result will be better.

Comment: @heynnema I have checked firmware it's up-to-date. I'm beginning to to re-install everything

Comment: @ShivakSIngh make sure to use GPT partitioning.

Comment: @heynnema I did this as well nothing changed

Comment: @ShivakSIngh  Sorry to hear that. Do backups still fail, as they did before? Any changes at all for the better?

Comment: @heynnema Backups are working fine thanks for your help.

Comment: @ShivakSIngh that's a good improvement. However, you still have slowness with your code?

Comment: @heynnema No that's rectified as well thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @ShivakSIngh great news! I've updated my answer. Please remember to accept it if all of this dialog helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu 18.xx partition...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

From the comments...

It was decided that it would be best to rebuild the system disk with a GPT partition table, and a fresh install of Windows and Ubuntu. Backup failures, and slow running user code have been solved.

Comment: I did this it executed without any error, it just said that the time was set to future. But nothing has changed.